# React: how to re-render tree component, when form submit in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a question regarding refreshing a component in react.
Page is displaying two components.
Left panel displaying tree component. Tree Node click route to the corresponding pages on the right side of page.
Problem: Components on the right include add/edit/delete nodes etc. Each node displays different components on the right, Ex: Add category form submit add a node without refreshing the page, without refreshing the right component. How to refresh a tree component on form submit without refreshing a page.
Please look into my working tree code in the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-snow-nfce4i
In my sandbox node routing is not working.

Also, the page looks like after clicking on Service node: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeYB6.gif

Please find my complete code in the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-pond-foqvpq

Please help in my code how to refresh a tree on form submit in other component without refreshing the complete page.

```
App.js
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ProductsTree from "./ProductsTreeView";
import AddCategory from "./Add_Category";
const initialState = {
  currentNode: {},
  data: ""
};

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
    this.productsTree = createRef();
    this.setCurrentNode = this.setCurrentNode.bind(this);
  }

  setCurrentNode(node) {
    this.setState({ currentNode: node });
  }
  ExpandAll() {
    this.productsTree.current.treeView.current.ExpandAll();
  }

  CollapseAll() {
    this.productsTree.current.treeView.current.CollapseAll();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div width="100%">
        <div
          width="50%"
          style={{
            height: "200px",
            border: "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            display: "inline-block"
          }}
        >
          <Link
            onClick={() => {
              this.ExpandAll();
            }}
          >
            <b>Expand All</b>
          </Link>{" "}
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <Link
            onClick={() => {
              this.CollapseAll();
            }}
          >
            <b>Minimize All</b>
          </Link>
          <ProductsTree
            ref={this.productsTree}
            setCurrentNode={this.setCurrentNode}
          />
        </div>
        <div
          width="50%"
          style={{
            border: "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
            display: "inline-block"
          }}
        >

        <Route path="/Add_Category"> 
          <AddCategory key_id={this.state.currentNode.key_id} />
        </Route> 
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import XMLParser from "react-xml-parser";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import plus from "./plus.gif";
import minus from "./minus.gif";
import paper from "./paper.gif";

const tree = `
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

<tree>

       <entity id="e11" key-id="1" link-page-name="Add_Category">
              <description>Service</description>
              <image>plus.gif</image>
              <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>
              <entity id="e248" key-id="48" link-page-name="Edit_Category">
                     <description>A_test1_test1</description>
                     <image>plus.gif</image>
                     <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>
                     <entity id="e3717" key-id="717" link-page-name="Edit_Product">
                           <description>A_SubItem1</description>
                           <image>plus.gif</image>                      <imageNode>de.gif</imageNode>
                           <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>
                           <entity id="e45546" key-id="5546" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">
                                  <description>A_Test_Template</description>
                                  <image>paper.gif</image>
                                  <imageOpen>paper.gif</imageOpen>
                           </entity>
                     </entity>
              </entity>
              <entity id="e264" key-id="64" link-page-name="Add_Product">
              <description>111AAAA</description>        
              <image>plus.gif</image>       
              <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>      
            </entity>   
            <entity id="e256" key-id="56" link-page-name="Add_Product">       
              <description>11323789</description>  
              <image>plus.gif</image>     
              <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>     
            </entity>
              <entity id="e247" key-id="47" link-page-name="Edit_Category">
                     <description>A_test6</description>
                     <image>plus.gif</image>
                     <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>

                     <entity id="e3716" key-id="716" link-page-name="Edit_Product">
                           <description>A_Item</description>
                           <image>plus.gif</image>
                           <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>
                           <entity id="e45545" key-id="5545" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">
                                  <description>temp1</description>
                                  <image>paper.gif</image>
                                  <imageOpen>paper.gif</imageOpen>

                           </entity>

                     </entity>

              </entity>

 

       </entity>

       <entity id="e12" key-id="2" link-page-name="Add_Category">

              <description>Sales</description>

              <image>plus.gif</image>

              <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>

              <entity id="e230" key-id="30" link-page-name="Edit_Category">

                     <description>Gift Cards</description>

                     <image>plus.gif</image>
                  <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>

                     <entity id="e3421" key-id="421" link-page-name="Edit_Product">

                           <description>Sample Card</description>

                           <image>plus.gif</image>
                           <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>

                           <entity id="e43308" key-id="3308" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">

                                  <description>greeting temp</description>

                                  <image>paper.gif</image>

                                  <imageOpen>paper.gif</imageOpen>

                           </entity>

                     </entity>

                     <entity id="e3422" key-id="422" link-page-name="Edit_Product">

                           <description>De Card</description>

                           <image>plus.gif</image>
                           <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>

                           <entity id="e43309" key-id="3309" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">

                                  <description>NS Temp</description>

                                  <image>paper.gif</image>

                                  <imageOpen>paper.gif</imageOpen>

                           </entity>

                     </entity>

 

              </entity>

              <entity id="e215" key-id="15" link-page-name="Edit_Category">

                     <description>Chck</description>

                     <image>plus.gif</image>

                     <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>

                     <entity id="e3671" key-id="671" link-page-name="Edit_Product">

                           <description>Add item</description>

                           <image>plus.gif</image>
                           <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>

                           <entity id="e45438" key-id="5438" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">

                                  <description>Ahhhh</description>

                                  <image>paper.gif</image>

                                  <imageOpen>paper.gif</imageOpen>

                           </entity>

                     </entity>

                     <entity id="e3450" key-id="450" link-page-name="Edit_Product">
                           <description>Advtttt</description>
                           <image>plus.gif</image>
                           <imageOpen>minus.gif</imageOpen>
                           <entity id="e43577" key-id="3577" link-page-name="Edit_ProdTemplate">
                                  <description>gggggg</description>
                                  <image>paper.gif</image>
                                  <imageOpen>paper.gif</imageOpen>
                           </entity>
                     </entity>
              </entity>
       </entity>

</tree>
`;

const StyledLI = styled.li`
  list-style-type: none;

  ::before {
    content: "";

    display: inline-flex;

    width: 16px;

    height: 16px;

    ${({ expanded, isPaper }) =>
      `background: url(${
        isPaper === paper ? paper : expanded ? minus : plus
      })};`};
  }
`;

class ProductsTreeView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.treeView = createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="TreeView">
        <TreeView
          ref={this.treeView}
          setCurrentNode={this.props.setCurrentNode}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Node {
  description = "n/a";

  id = -1;

  key_id = -1;

  linkpagename = "";

  icon = "";

  isActive = false;

  nodes = [];

  constructor(description, id, key_id, icon, linkpagename) {
    this.description = description;

    this.id = id;

    this.key_id = key_id;

    this.icon = icon;

    this.linkpagename = linkpagename;
  }

  static nodesFromXml(xml) {
    const map = (entity, nodes) => {
      const id = entity.attributes["id"];

      const key_id = entity.attributes["key-id"];

      const descriptionText =
        entity.children[
          entity.children.findIndex((child) => child.name === "description")
        ].value;

      const entities = entity.children.filter(
        (child) => child.name === "entity"
      );

      var linkPageName = entity.attributes["link-page-name"];

      linkPageName = linkPageName.replace(".aspx", "");

      const icon =
        entity.children[
          entity.children.findIndex((child) => child.name === "imageOpen")
        ].value;

      const node = new Node(descriptionText, id, key_id, icon, linkPageName);

      nodes.push(node);

      entities.forEach((entity) => map(entity, node.nodes));
    };

    const parsedData = new XMLParser().parseFromString(xml);

    const entities = parsedData.children.filter(
      (child) => child.name === "entity"
    );

    const nodes = [];

    entities.forEach((entity) => map(entity, nodes));

    return nodes;
  }
}

class TreeView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      //  nodes: []
      nodes: Node.nodesFromXml(tree)
    };

    this.toggleNode = this.toggleNode.bind(this);

    this.CollapseAll = this.CollapseAll.bind(this);

    this.ExpandAll = this.ExpandAll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // axios
    //   .get(tree, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })
    //   .then((response) =>{
    //     console.log({ response })
    //     // this.setState({ nodes: Node.nodesFromXml(response.data) })
    //   })
    //   .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
  }

  render() {
    const nodes = this.state.nodes;

    return (
      <div>
        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="left">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Products</b>
            </td>
            <td width="50%" style={{ textAlign: "right" }}></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

        <ul>
          {nodes.map((node) => (
            <TreeNode
              id={node.id}
              key={node.key_id}
              node={node}
              onToggle={this.toggleNode}
              setCurrentNode={this.props.setCurrentNode}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

  toggleNode(node) {
    const { nodes } = this.state;

    this.props.setCurrentNode(node);

    function _toggleNode(currentNode, node, isActive) {
      if (isActive !== undefined) {
        currentNode.isActive = isActive;
      } else if (currentNode.id === node.id) {
        if (currentNode.key_id === node.key_id) {
          currentNode.isActive = !currentNode.isActive;
        }
      }

      currentNode.nodes.forEach((childNode) =>
        _toggleNode(childNode, node, currentNode.isActive ? undefined : false)
      );
    }

    nodes.forEach((currentNode) => _toggleNode(currentNode, node));

    this.setState((state) => (state.nodes = nodes));
  }

  CollapseAll() {
    const { nodes } = this.state;

    function _collapseAll(currentNode) {
      currentNode.isActive = false;

      currentNode.nodes.forEach((childNode) => _collapseAll(childNode));
    }

    nodes.forEach((currentNode) => _collapseAll(currentNode));

    this.setState((state) => (state.nodes = nodes));
  }

  ExpandAll() {
    const { nodes } = this.state;

    function _expandAll(currentNode) {
      currentNode.isActive = true;

      currentNode.nodes.forEach((childNode) => _expandAll(childNode));
    }

    nodes.forEach((currentNode) => _expandAll(currentNode));

    this.setState((state) => (state.nodes = nodes));
  }
}

class TreeNode extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { node, onToggle } = this.props;

    const activeChildren =
      node.isActive && node.nodes.length ? (
        <ul style={{ paddingLeft: "1.8rem" }}>
          {node.nodes.map((node) => (
            <TreeNode
              id={node.id}
              key={node.key_id}
              node={node}
              onToggle={onToggle}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : null;

    return (
      <Link
        to={node.linkpagename}
        key={node.key_id}
        onClick={(event) => {
          event.stopPropagation();

          onToggle(node);
        }}
        style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#000000" }}
      >
        <StyledLI
          id={node.id}
          expanded={node.isActive}
          isPaper={node.icon}
          isLeaf={!node.nodes.length}
        >
          {node.description}

          {/*- {node.key_id} - {node.linkpagename}*/}

          {activeChildren}
        </StyledLI>
      </Link>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductsTreeView;

import React from "react";
export class Add_Category extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ID: "",
      CategoryName: "",
      ValidationStatus: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ CategoryName: event.target.value });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const ID = this.props.key_id;
    const CategoryName = this.state.CategoryName;
    const data = { ID, CategoryName };
    fetch("url", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      credentials: "include",
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          ValidationStatus: data
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error:", error));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {" "}
        Add Form
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <br />
          Name:{" "}
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.CategoryName}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            size="50"
            maxLength="50"
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <button type="Submit" className="SaveButton">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Add_Category;
```

Comment: Please help how to refresh a tree component on the form submit in the (Add category) component. Highly appreciate for the help.

Comment: Try [lifting the tree view state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the closest common ancestor (*looks like `App`*) and pass the state and state update function down as props to each `ProductsTree` and `AddCategory` so each panel can easily read and update a single common state object.

Comment: Hi Drew, I am not sure how to lift the state up. Please update in my sandbox. highly appreciate for the help.

Comment: @TestUser, I guess I've fixed the routing. At least Add_Category loads now while the home is still in place. It looks like you need to change your web app's general approach and layout.  The parent "/" route must point at the layout component that creates the structure of your web site (left and right panels). It should also contain your tree control. Inside that route you need an additional route responsible for the content (like Add_Categories or Home).

Comment: Hi Rallen, Routing is not my issue. That issue is only in the sandbox. My code in visual studio is working fine. Problem is add_category component add a node in the top level1 node. Form submit in add_category component add a node. Please fix my code so that form submit in add_category component refreshes the ProductsTreeView component.

Comment: Hi Drew, Please help. how to lift the tree view state up in the code.

Comment: Hi Drew, Please look into my code in the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-pond-foqvpq.   Add_Category form will open when Service node will be clicked. Please help how to refresh the tree on form submit.

Comment: Hi Drew, I read the article that you suggested lifting the tree view state up.  I am not sure how to implement this in my code. Please look into my code in the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-pond-foqvpq                         
    Add_Category form will open when Service node will be clicked. Please help how to refresh the tree on form submit.

Comment: Hi Experts, Please help how to refresh the tree on form submit from Add_Category component.

Comment: Hi Drew, please check my sandbox. Code is working. I am not able to understand how to refresh tree on form submit

Comment: Please have a look at this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/update-component-based-on-other-component-updated-pfsquk. I hope this will works for you.

Comment: I think as long as this tree/node structure/object is outside React state and directly mutated in handlers you'll have synchronization issues. Can you walk us through the UI in https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-pond-foqvpq and explain what a user should do and what you expect the app to do? In other words, a set of reproduction steps?

Comment: On page load, just tree is going to display. On click on level1 nodes like Service and Service, add_category form is going to open in the right side of the page. Now the url routes to: http:..../app_category.      On click of level2 nodes, page route to edit_category. Problem comes here User is adding a category from the add_category form on form submit. Form submit should not refresh the complete page. Form submit jusr refresh the tree in the left so that new added node will be shown. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you should hire a developer to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to deal with this type of data change notification across UI views can be to use an event bus pattern. Here is a React example:

**ADD AN EVENT BUS**

```bash
npm install js-event-bus --save
```

**DEFINE AN EVENT TYPE**

```js
export class ItemAddedEvent {
    public readonly itemName: string
}
```

**RAISE THE EVENT**

In your AddCategory module, raise an event like this after your fetch POST to the backend:

```js
props.eventBus.emit('ItemAdded', null, new ItemAddedEvent('somename'));
```

**CONSUME THE EVENT**

In your ProductsTreeView module, consume the event like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    startup();
    return () => cleanup();
}, []);

function startup(): {
    props.eventBus.on('ItemAdded', onItemAdded);
}

function cleanup() {
    props.eventBus.detach('ItemAdded', onItemAdded);
}

function onItemAdded(event: ItemAddedEvent) {
    // update the tree view state here
}
```

**EVENT BUS CREATION**

You can create the event bus instance at [application startup](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/app/appViewModel.ts) (eg. in index.js), then pass it as `props` to all views that need it.

**SUMMARY**

To just notify the immediate parent, I instead use a simple callback supplied in props. When more traversal across views is needed I tend to use events. Here are a few sample UIs of mine that use this design pattern:

- [React SPA](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/views/companies/companiesContainer.tsx)
- [React Desktop App](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/src/views/companies/companiesContainer.tsx)
- [Kotlin Android App](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authsamples/basicmobileapp/views/companies/CompaniesFragment.kt)
- [Swift iOS App](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios/blob/master/Source/Views/Companies/CompaniesView.swift)